# what are good ways to debug c++ runtime error?

Tags: c++, debugging, address-sanitizer

What are good ways to debug the following problem?

I tried to use address sanitizer and set break point in Clion running the code in ubuntu. None of them provide helpful debug message to locate the problem.

```
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34
```

The following code coming from this problem can reproduce the runtime error:

```
https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-length-of-pair-chain/
```

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;


class Solution {
public:
    int findLongestChain(vector<vector<int>> &pairs) {


        int n = pairs.size();
        if (n == 0) return 0;
        sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), [](vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b) { return a[1] <= b[1]; });


        int lastRight = pairs[0][1];
        int res = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (pairs[i][0] > lastRight) {
                res++;
                lastRight = pairs[i][1];
            }

        }

        return res;

    }
};

int main() {

    vector<vector<int>> pairs = {{-994,-938},{19,592},{-232,-209},{788,937},{772,838},{741,801},{-229,747},{242,907},{-592,730},{-517,996},{380,693},{98,662},{-760,169},{-844,541},{-535,461},{-544,138},{-799,390},{-998,-965},{680,1000},{-73,698},{-955,51},{-909,-891},{-61,558},{217,357},{-721,108},{351,421},{608,903},{449,615},{-31,165},{979,998},{-849,-69},{627,974},{-880,918},{-766,209},{178,695},{266,917},{518,763},{-183,665},{878,996},{77,430},{-906,-403},{136,594},{-694,-525},{806,845},{-445,8},{-813,687},{-730,247},{909,925},{-360,741},{-418,-199},{-111,498},{367,873},{341,664},{-27,14},{-450,814},{-405,-117},{249,932},{703,864},{141,888},{278,646},{-851,-804},{-956,-819},{192,686},{-779,69},{-803,-502},{619,969},{-973,14},{-659,-136},{340,951},{-31,137},{-801,-701},{189,323},{107,615},{403,918},{452,753},{-224,-6},{697,959},{312,787},{-862,-398},{634,971},{-645,-148},{464,613},{570,592},{710,910},{-422,-139},{-148,360},{572,716},{905,909},{237,709},{-636,274},{-759,-693},{-937,112},{796,879},{-927,857},{-861,-767},{898,946},{667,719},{-234,-94},{259,911},{-870,-125},{-378,-138},{593,712},{-572,-219},{160,387},{-72,480},{870,943},{-182,669},{-713,-151},{-859,-524},{108,371},{-861,786},{17,579},{205,644},{-527,312},{752,933},{113,896},{-164,100},{-128,961},{-998,986},{551,757},{388,990},{-211,530},{853,886},{-174,762},{700,912},{-708,-655},{-414,793},{362,828},{556,850},{-501,-437},{39,215},{-311,-115},{-798,122},{965,995},{-84,246},{-469,-95},{581,841},{-625,-430},{347,561},{-969,-43},{362,412},{-829,850},{-17,571},{-763,784},{-591,776},{700,877},{619,855},{-222,895},{-340,436},{-651,-9},{-836,-361},{458,987},{653,975},{-105,-66},{261,924},{715,803},{107,235},{809,958},{17,46},{-856,140},{-311,835},{-185,146},{-348,200},{338,662},{170,495},{687,902},{-889,-622},{-886,-117},{-11,679},{-496,196},{-314,-242},{-238,194},{510,658},{237,826},{-977,505},{-326,311},{-207,416},{563,979},{-526,536},{698,843},{522,829},{135,505},{-959,253},{19,258},{-945,-105},{-229,906},{798,978},{-857,-452},{-56,320},{309,649},{143,328},{-195,-8},{-464,320},{-172,13},{68,332},{-713,-74},{936,966},{276,860},{-425,334},{-461,730},{852,938},{-828,-818},{-562,-6},{-722,723},{945,975},{165,989},{-629,274},{484,486},{977,995},{-378,263},{3,836},{-661,-558},{-384,839},{-783,237},{719,795},{-52,768},{521,949},{-235,107},{846,885},{-257,159},{-447,461},{202,550},{902,977},{558,983},{830,882},{-174,631},{-424,926},{248,521},{107,173},{97,738},{-593,-441},{302,435},{703,792},{-994,308},{-543,926},{-794,398},{936,984},{-422,-107},{-122,982},{834,836},{-694,63},{341,755},{442,672},{-866,647},{545,978},{352,700},{73,635},{-201,-123},{-237,140},{-395,205},{921,968},{-806,166},{-951,256},{436,863},{-996,-435},{853,907},{-999,-686},{443,506},{788,827},{-133,238},{-630,284},{934,939},{-385,536},{387,637},{547,565},{919,927},{-271,742},{-263,141},{-359,712},{-323,-18},{494,674},{348,526},{-537,-437},{911,935},{936,953},{15,829},{-666,874},{-808,496},{-393,366},{957,974},{681,961},{-747,-420},{-713,-213},{445,782},{900,952},{348,562},{-929,957},{622,667},{725,837},{177,931},{959,969},{-156,466},{680,966},{-869,-822},{313,785},{-627,469},{-313,518},{-626,498},{29,754},{83,386},{-502,506},{-672,647},{-507,47},{393,553},{293,312},{-524,-100},{325,350},{-817,31},{-421,695},{-400,227},{-387,-9},{-556,412},{732,763},{-18,394},{-478,-370},{-326,-305},{254,997},{-341,837},{-727,859},{349,451},{-335,202},{-540,-481},{186,272},{647,975},{-281,919},{284,758},{-500,58},{464,828},{479,628},{828,1000},{-500,-132},{-41,532},{734,995},{3,232},{-358,185},{669,807},{-524,501},{-240,608},{75,683},{833,923},{-454,917},{707,858},{322,651},{887,974},{63,263},{-705,462},{-606,366},{-792,-699},{5,315},{265,573},{-735,461},{632,755},{250,329},{861,915},{-93,577},{-107,-2},{164,313},{-222,72},{165,343},{600,639},{-954,-355},{682,700},{195,387},{263,649},{532,642},{732,919},{-321,-219},{423,701},{-2,638},{-697,591},{474,921},{266,481},{-80,51},{305,906},{-265,242},{896,963},{-930,120},{877,932},{453,599},{-851,486},{-571,-28},{-659,597},{-72,978},{-494,385},{686,797},{40,874},{-245,115},{23,680},{-950,34},{-763,558},{464,786},{-4,566},{-289,-102},{92,799},{628,887},{301,813},{355,414},{-452,865},{41,587},{816,983},{887,953},{-4,753},{-112,10},{12,554},{-1000,994},{-332,142},{653,965},{419,453},{612,687},{-205,877},{-931,-548},{-686,61},{371,944},{-740,837},{-622,196},{-604,-45},{913,957},{741,808},{355,470},{666,938},{-79,235},{53,126},{-250,5},{40,584},{806,975},{-29,416},{352,835},{-914,-733},{-171,809},{651,935},{-893,-364},{33,433},{506,856},{682,725},{-380,476},{-542,-135},{478,571},{-986,13},{871,947},{698,845},{-255,259},{-52,247},{-953,494},{920,964},{-996,622},{249,858},{243,739},{199,644},{467,862},{-262,-130},{754,908},{-408,990},{885,951},{978,996},{-506,740},{-437,536},{542,750},{695,891},{564,601},{-388,760},{257,908},{348,615},{558,989},{106,214},{-163,922},{396,788},{-980,-381},{-477,450},{-144,741},{551,770},{642,979},{-91,314},{595,840},{-391,349},{-751,541},{618,912},{9,213},{953,962},{-377,728},{-53,566},{-809,485},{-275,111},{221,658},{340,903},{-964,448},{279,554},{666,742},{-818,-13},{934,963},{-396,877},{320,472},{-257,-186},{536,927}};


    cout << Solution().findLongestChain(pairs);

}
```

edit:
The original intention was to seek suggestions for debugging tools. Looks like such a tool does not exist for the example problem given.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- Please use the appropriate header files, not this one.

Comment: How would you identify UB if,- by definition (!) -, any arbitrary behavior can occur? You may generally track for ***anomalies***, but that's all not very helpful, since one of the anomalies includes, that the code works exactly as expected by the author, and the behavior only changes, if a completely unrelated part of it is changed (e.g. order of function calls, which changed the stack ontents in a specific manner).

Comment: Similar to having run-time array-bounds checking, the runtime in some sort of "debug" mode needs to provide explicit checks for violations of the sort criteria.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie To some degree, yes. But think about a (non instrumented) function, which spuriously writes over the context stack area of a calling function. Effect may be something that triggers the instrumented calling function to have shown UB,, and where it's discovered is still completely unrelated to where the real bug sits.

Answer (score 2):

One issue is this:

```
sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), [](vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b) 
 { return a[1] <= b[1]; });  // <-- Not a strict-weak-ordering.
```

The sort criteria must be a [strict-weak-ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/strict_weak_order).  Any sort criteria that has `<=` or `>=` are always suspect of violating this rule.  A violation of the strict-weak-order rule leads to undefined behavior.

The fix is to compare that the item is strictly less than the other.

```
sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), [](vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b) 
 { return a[1] < b[1]; });
```

---

Please note:

If you're using Visual Studio, the debug runtime does this exact check for ordering violations like this. The comparison function is called twice, the first time with A,B order, and the second time with B,A order. The return values for each call are compared, and an assert() will occur if there is a violation.

Comment: I had the impression OP asked, how generally identify UB using the debugger (beyond a particular compiler warning you'll get when lucky). But may be I was mislead. Other than that I believe that's not possible barely using the debugger, or any dependency injected sanitizer frameworks (see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66523820/what-are-good-ways-to-debug-c-runtime-error#comment117601031_66523820)).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie,  Thank you! your fix solved the code problem which solves the leetcode problem. However, I am still interested in knowing the problem mentioned in the title of this post. So looks like this code example is not a good motivating example.

Comment: @cpchung See my edit. I don't know if the compiler you're using has this type of checking mechanism at runtime. Probably the runtime has to provide this.

Comment: I am using ubuntu, is there similar way to do the same as yours in Window with Visual Studio?  my environment: `gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 
`

Comment: You have to check the documentation if g++ has a debug version that has this functionality.  I believe there is, but not sure.